Subfield of field of rational functions is either the base field or contains a nontrivial polynomial
Let $F$ be a field and $\mathrm{char}~F = 0$. Suppose that there is a chain of field extensions $F \subset K \subset F(x)$, where the latter is a field of rational functions. I want to prove that if $K \subset F(x)$ is an infinite extension, then $K=F$.
If it was possible to choose a nonconstant irreducible polynomial $f(x) \in K$, then we would have $F(f(x)) \subset K \subset F(x)$ and $[F(x):K] \leq [F(x) : F(f(x))] = \mathrm{deg}~f$, a contradiction.
But I don't know how to generally find such element, because an arbitrary element must be a fraction, not a polynomial.

This is Lüroth's theorem and it says that any field field $K$ with $F\subset K\subseteq F(x) $ can be written as $K=F(u) $ for some $u\in F(x) \setminus F$. Moreover degree $[F(x) : K] $ equals $\max(\text{deg }a(x), \text{deg }b(x)) $ where $u=a(x) /b(x)$ and $a(x), b(x) $ are relatively prime polynomials in $F[x] $. Further there is a stronger version which says that if $K$ contains a non-constant polynomial then $u$ can be choosen to lie in $F[x] $.

In general, if $K$ is an intermediate field between $F$ and $F(x)$, it can happen that $K\neq F$ and contains no polynomials other than the constant ones. Of course, we cannot find such an example satisfying the condition that $[F(x):K]$ is infinite because a posteriori such example must be just $F$.
Take $K=F(\alpha)$ with $\alpha = x + \frac{1}{x}$. Note that the field automorphism $\sigma:F(x)\to F(x)$ given by $f(x)\mapsto f\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)$ restricts to the identity on $K$. Thus if $f(x)\in K$ is a polynomial, then
$$
f(x)=f\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)
$$
which implies that $\deg(f)=0$, that is $f$ must be a constant.
But you don't need the existence of an irreducible non constant polynomial in $K$ to conclude. Assume that $K\neq F$ and let $\alpha$ be an element in $K$ but not in $F$. Write
$$
\alpha = \frac{a(x)}{b(x)}.
$$
Note that
$$
P(Y) = a(Y)-\alpha b(Y)\in K[Y]
$$
is a non constant polynomial such that $P(x)=0$. This means that $x$ is algebraic over $K$ and consequently that $[K(x):K]$ is finite. But
$$
K(x) = F(\alpha,x) = F(x),
$$
so that $[F(x):K]$ is finite.

I have an extra question: would $P(Y)$ be a minimal polynomial of $x$?

If $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ have no common factor, then $P(Y)$ is, up to nonzero constant in $K$, the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $K$.
